# Как в Oracle сдампить только структуру БД?

Tags: oracle, dump

Т.е. только схему без данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

**Первый способ** позволяет сдампить структуру с помощью SQL-запроса, используя встроенную функцию *GET_DDL*.

Вот такой запрос запишет данные в файл db_schema.sql, если таблицы принадлежат пользователю.

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000
set feedback off
set echo off 
spool db_schema.sql 
connect login/password;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name) FROM USER_TABLES u;
spool off;
```

Если таблицы не принадлежат пользователю, то можно сделать выборку не из USER_TABLES, а из ALL__TABLES и фильтровать по какому-нибудь условию.

**Второй способ** это запуск приложения, которая идет в поставке сервера. В версии ниже 10-ой это делается примерно так:

```
EXP 'login/password' owner=DB_OWNER file=c:\abc.dmp
```

Подробнее прочитать тут: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

В версии, начиная с 10-ой так:

```
expdp login/password@database_name schemas=SCHEME_NAME directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=dumpFileName.dmp logfile=exportDB.log
```

Подробнее прочитать тут: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php